# Blazor quick grid not populating with data correctly

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Eeven if I have my data source as IEnumerable a cant seem to get data to show in quick grid.

I even tried my list as a IQUERYABLE and that has not fixied the situation at all any ideas at all?

My code is showing weird to Im using VS2022 17.5 Preview 1

[image]
Im trying to follow the docs here

https://aspnet.github.io/quickgridsamples/columns

```
<QuickGrid Items="@playersList">
  <PropertyColumn  Property="@(c => c.FullName)" Sortable="true"  />       
</QuickGrid>

@code {

public IEnumerable<Players> playersList { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Authentication auth = new Authentication();
    auth.Email = myuser.Username;
    myuser.Password = myuser.Password;
    string jwtTown =await  api.GenerateBarrerToken(myuser);
    auth.JWTToken = jwtTown;
    db.SaveAutheneticationAysnc(auth);

    playersList = await api.GetALLPlayers();
    playersList = playersList.AsEnumerable();
}
```

You will see my model does have FullName

```
public class Players
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public int? OrginizationId { get; set; }

    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public int? CoachId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    public string? PlayerLevel { get; set; }
    public string? FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + Surname; }
    }
```

}
There is 800 Records here so I dont see why I get Blank grid?

[image]

My cs proj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid" Version="0.1.0-alpha.22351.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3" Version="2.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.Core" Version="20.3.0.56" />
      <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grid" Version="20.3.0.56" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\APP.Bal\APP.Bal.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\APP.Dal\APP.Dal.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\APP.Models\APP.Models.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\APPServices\APP.Services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Even ic i charge to iquerable as said it dont display my columns

Comment: As Henk says, provide more info to help us to help you

Comment: I just looked at the `OnInitializedAsync` and I can see two `await` calls: when this happens Blazor often does not refresh the UI after the _first_ await, so it's necessary to call `StateHasChanged();` to notify Blazor that it needs to refresh UI. Put this call as the last statement in that method.

Answer (score -1):

This was actually a bug in there documentation for the quick grid.
It requried the

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid
```

To be at the top of the page